# CSS Positioning in html

Tags: html, css

How to align the images width the hight of the text column? I use relative position but it doesn't work.

[image]

```css
.bungkus-komentar {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  min-height: 100px;
}
.div-komentar {
  width: 85%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green;
}
.div-penjawab {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  width: 10%;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.div-penjawab img {}
```

```html
<div class="bungkus-komentar">
  <div class="div-komentar">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="div-penjawab">
    <img class="img-circle" src="http://bakerhi.com/wp-content/themes/nucleare-pro/images/no-image-box.png" width='100%' height='100%'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: do you want to position all your images vertically in that area ?

Comment: I mean how height image element follows the text element??

Comment: yup vert3x,. how?

Comment: there are default values (that are top and left) when talking about alignment. If you need to align an element vertically you can use jquery (read the height of the container and force it to take this value as margin) or using rem margin on css.

Comment: for example please?

Answer (score 0):

something like that?

```css
.bungkus-komentar {
    display:flex;
    background: blue;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.div-komentar{
    width: 85%;
    float: left;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:green;
}
.div-penjawab {
    background: yellow;
    margin :1px;
    padding:1px;
    width: 10%;
   height: 50px;
    float: left;
}
.div-penjawab img {
}
```

```html
<div class="bungkus-komentar">

<div class="div-komentar">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>

<div class="div-penjawab">
<img class="img-circle" src="http://bakerhi.com/wp-content/themes/nucleare-pro/images/no-image-box.png" width='100%' height='100%'>
</div>

</div>

<div class="bungkus-komentar">

<div class="div-komentar">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>

<div class="div-penjawab">
<img class="img-circle" src="http://bakerhi.com/wp-content/themes/nucleare-pro/images/no-image-box.png" width='100%' height='100%'>
</div>

</div>

<div class="bungkus-komentar">

<div class="div-komentar">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>

<div class="div-penjawab">
<img class="img-circle" src="http://bakerhi.com/wp-content/themes/nucleare-pro/images/no-image-box.png" width='100%' height='100%'>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for?

I used absolute positionning in the right and left containers, table display  and a middle vertical-align for the left container that contains all images and each image container have a table-row display. Hope it helps you.

```css
.bungkus-komentar {
}

.div-komentar {
  height:auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 85%;
  height:100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}

.container {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 15%;
  height:100%;
  display: table;
  vertical-align :middle;
}

.div-penjawab {
  display: table-row;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  width:100%
}

.div-penjawab img {height: 50px;}
```

```html
<div class="bungkus-komentar">
  <div class="div-komentar">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui amet esse quas quam laudantium adipisci vel fugit aspernatur. Modi eius, odit dicta sapiente unde mollitia! Ad vero nam sequi culpa. Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui amet esse quas quam laudantium adipisci vel fugit aspernatur. Modi eius, odit dicta sapiente unde mollitia! Ad vero nam sequi culpa. Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui amet esse quas quam laudantium adipisci vel fugit aspernatur. Modi eius, odit dicta sapiente unde mollitia! Ad vero nam sequi culpa. Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui amet esse quas quam laudantium adipisci vel fugit aspernatur. Modi eius, odit dicta sapiente unde mollitia! Ad vero nam sequi culpa.</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="div-penjawab">
    <img class="img-circle" src="http://bakerhi.com/wp-content/themes/nucleare-pro/images/no-image-box.png" width='100%' height='100%'>
  </div>
  <div class="div-penjawab">
    <img class="img-circle" src="http://bakerhi.com/wp-content/themes/nucleare-pro/images/no-image-box.png" width='100%' height='100%'>
  </div>
  <div class="div-penjawab">
    <img class="img-circle" src="http://bakerhi.com/wp-content/themes/nucleare-pro/images/no-image-box.png" width='100%' height='100%'>
  </div>
  <div class="div-penjawab">
    <img class="img-circle" src="http://bakerhi.com/wp-content/themes/nucleare-pro/images/no-image-box.png" width='100%' height='100%'>
  </div>
  <div class="div-penjawab">
    <img class="img-circle" src="http://bakerhi.com/wp-content/themes/nucleare-pro/images/no-image-box.png" width='100%' height='100%'>
  </div>
  <div class="div-penjawab">
    <img class="img-circle" src="http://bakerhi.com/wp-content/themes/nucleare-pro/images/no-image-box.png" width='100%' height='100%'>
  </div>
  <div class="div-penjawab">
    <img class="img-circle" src="http://bakerhi.com/wp-content/themes/nucleare-pro/images/no-image-box.png" width='100%' height='100%'>
  </div>
  <div class="div-penjawab">
    <img class="img-circle" src="http://bakerhi.com/wp-content/themes/nucleare-pro/images/no-image-box.png" width='100%' height='100%'>
  </div>
  <div class="div-penjawab">
    <img class="img-circle" src="http://bakerhi.com/wp-content/themes/nucleare-pro/images/no-image-box.png" width='100%' height='100%'>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hut3r3we/3/).

Comment: no,. i want if div-komentar have text and so long, then div-penjawab automatically followed

Comment: Sorry I thought you wanted to have a column containing images with vertical align, If you want to have equal height columns this might helps you http://callmenick.com/post/css-equal-height-columns-three-different-ways